# How can I synchronize Hololens with Android device?

Tags: android, hololens, data-capture

I would like to extract data from both a microsoft Hololens and an android device. However, the data needs to have a synchronized timestamp. i.e. I need to start collecting data from both at the same time and know the offset between the two in ms (for example).

If possible I would also like to send and receive data between the two devices.

Has anyone had experience with this ? What was your solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from [HoloToolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloToolkit) sharing platform. It's a multi platform framework that enables real time communication between devices and its presently used to create HoloLens shared experiences. 
It has helper classes and libraries for C# (unity, WPF, UWP) and Java so you could potentially adapt it - not without some effort - to Android.
This is to my knowledge the closest there is to a fully functional communication and syncronization mechanism for Holo

Comment: Thank you Alex for your response. I will let you know if I manage to achieve something useful.

Comment: you should totally check the official hololens forum where there are a lot more hololens uses than here. Not to say anything wrong about SO. Also, don't hestate to upvote or accept the answer if it helped you.